# Eth::Client::ContractExecutionError - transaction underpriced

Tags: ruby, rubygems, blockchain, polygon

I am using the eth gem ruby library https://q9f.github.io/eth.rb/ to execute a function called from the ABI but it keeps getting the error transaction underpriced. I assume that it has something to do with the gas price so I set a gas price and is still giving me the error. Mind you that call functions that depending on getting information like "balanceOf" works fine.

code:

```
def self.mint(mint_address, mint_amount)
      signer = Eth::Key.new(priv: @@private_key)

      client = Eth::Client.create "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/API"
      
      contract_name = "WOW"
      wow_contract = Eth::Contract.from_abi(abi: @@abiWOW.to_json, address:  @@master_contract_address, name: contract_name)
      wow_contract.key = signer

      # Convert Gwei to Wei for the gas price. 1 Gwei = 1e9 Wei.
      gas_price = 170 * 1e9

      # Set gas_price for the contract
      wow_contract.gas_price = gas_price
      wow_contract.gas_limit = 200000

      puts "gas price: #{wow_contract.gas_price}"
           
      mint_amount_in_smallest_unit = (mint_amount.to_f * (10**18)).to_i

      tx_hash = client.transact_and_wait(wow_contract, "mint", mint_address, mint_amount_in_smallest_unit, sender_key: signer)

      if client.tx_mined?(tx_hash)
        puts "Transaction was successful!"
      else
        puts "Transaction failed!"
      end
  end
```

Error:

```
Eth::Client::ContractExecutionError - transaction underpriced
```

Other output:

```
gas price: 170000000000.0
```

The network is Polygon and the client is Alchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the gas price. Try 2-3x of price according to current Gas Estimator of Blockchain, If you are using metamask, There is section in metamask to play with gas send. You can check that. Metamask have one blog on this. Please read that.